# Algebra of subsets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $ X  \neq \emptyset $ and $ C \subset P(X) $, we define the algebra generated by a collection of subsets as:

$ F(C) = \displaystyle\cap_{C \subseteq A} \; A \qquad $ with $ \qquad A: $ algebra of subsets of X.
Let $ E \subseteq X .\quad$ Prove that:

$ F(C) \cap E = F(C \cap E)$
I have to show that:

1. $ F(C) \cap E \subseteq  F(C \cap E) $
2. $  F(C \cap E) \subseteq F(C) \cap E  $

Well, I don't know how it is an element of the set $  F(C)  $. I think that:

If $ X \in F(C) = \displaystyle\cap_{C \subseteq A} A \quad \leftrightarrow \quad X \in A_1 \; \forall C \; \subseteq A_1 $.  Is it right?

Also, who looks like the set $ F(C \cap E) $ ?

$ F(C \cap E) = \displaystyle\cap_{C\cap E \;  \subseteq A}  A $

Comment: I think the equality you're looking for is: $F(C)\cap F(E) = F(C \cap E)$.

Comment: You mean  (and should write) $F(C)=\cap \{A: A\supset C\land A$ is an algebra of subsets of $X\}.$... And $F(C)\cap E$  and $F(C)\cap E $ make no sense